# Applied PDE's book suggestion

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am searching for a book on applied PDEs which do not focus on how to solve them, but instead different areas where they appear and what can we do with them. Maybe a book in which each chapter shows applications of pdes in areas like economics, finance, physics, biology, social sciences, etc... .I also would be nice if it contains some numerical ways to use them. Can you suggest one book like that to me?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which level you are aiming for. For undergraduate level, the book "Partial Differential Equations An Introduction" by Walter A. Strauss is decent (but it does not contain too much material on numerical PDE methods). For graduate level PDE, the classical book "Partial Equation Equations" by L.C.Evans seems quite popular.

Comment: wait, evans is applied?

Comment: It's not like other purely applied PDE textbooks as it introduces the Sobolev spaces and some modern PDE language... But I feel Evans PDE is quite standard in a graduate course on PDE...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I know those books on pdes, but they are not what I'm looking for. I need a book that emphasize where pdes appear (Not only the classical ones) and how they are useful, not only on the theory we use to solve them. I am more interested in how they are used, which phenomena they describe in various fields.